# jenkins cant pull from git repository using windows batch command

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

when i build my jenkins project i want to pull it first from my git repository so the code is up to date, i can see `git status` and `git --version` normally, but when it come to `git pull` the console output stuck on loading like this:

[image: jenkins command result]

When i try the exact same command and same dir in command prompt i can pull successfully in less than 2 seconds

[image: CMD command result]

is there anything that make different between jenkins command and cmd command?
i use windows xp with ssh to authenticating with git repository.

Comment: Are you the same user (anonymous) in the console as well as in the Jenkins job?

Comment: no, how to change that anonymous in jenkins? i can only change the name but not the userid

Comment: Actually, 'anonymous' just means you are not login. What I meant is: is Jenkins run with the same user as in your console? Could you add a build step with "`set`" in it, in order to print the user environment variable? `ssh` looks for the keys in `%HOME%\.ssh`. Is `HOME` set in your console? Is it set in the context of the Jenkins job? (hence the request for a `set` in a build step in the Jenkins job).

Comment: isn't the way to print environment variable is by using `echo %PATH%`? i set it on the environment variable but i don't know about _set in the context of the Jenkins job_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ssh` is used, it is crucial to make sure `HOME` is set when the job is executed: `ssh` will look for `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` (private and public keys) under `%HOME%\.ssh`.

In doubt, one can use the [**EnvInject** plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) which will add environment variables for a given job.