# Jenkins : use Execute Windows Batch command to run GIT commands : change user

Tags: git, authentication, jenkins, execute

I have spent a lot of time on this. This is not a duplicate of [the cygwin post that is first on google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018124/using-the-execute-shell-command-in-jenkins-to-run-git-commands-on-a-windows-mach).

Normal GIT Repo works with credentials - I have many projects on Jenkins, using GIT, and they all work fine. These repo's take the repository URL and credentials and branch, and obviously uses GIT to operate.

Now, I need to execute a GIT command. It is a simple `git tfs pull` and `git push.`

When I run these commands in console, it works fine. When I put it into a batch file and execute it myself, it runs fine. When I run the commands in "Execute Windows Batch command", then it hangs and does not execute.

I suspect it requires credentials. I do not know how to send the credentials for the batch command.

I [have run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985386/jenkins-cant-pull-from-git-repository-using-windows-batch-command) the `set` command, and can confirm that the user that is running during Jenkins execution, is not the same user when I run in command prompt.

How do I set the user to run this batch command as?

Comment: Are you using https url? or ssh url?

Comment: I am using https url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) will use as credential manager the [Credential Manager of Windows](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2016/01/the-windows-vaults/), through the [Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows).

Check the output of

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config credential.helper
```

This is using credentials cached for a given user. One alternative would be to set those credentials in a simple text file (for testing): See "[Git Tools - Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)".

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config credential.helper store --file /path/to/repo/.git/.my-credentials
```

That way, any user in that repo would use the right credentials.